# Filling Pixels Based On Line Coverage

Tags: c++, geometry

I am building a slicer. As a part of it, I want to find all pixels the each line crosses, and and give them a value between 0-255 based on the coverage of the line for each pixel. If pixel:
(x0,y0), (x1,y0), (x0,y1), (x1,y1)
Is crossed in 2 points:
(x2,y2), (x3,y3)
I'll do:

```
double x_overlap = std::abs(x3 - x2);
double y_overlap = std::abs(y3 - y2);
double total_pixel_area = std::abs(x1 - x0) * std::abs(y1 - y0);
double line_coverage_percentage = (x_overlap * y_overlap) / total_pixel_area;

// Calculate the pixel coverage value between 0 and 255 based on the percentage
int pixel_cover = static_cast<int>(line_coverage_percentage * 255);
```

now, for the hard part:
I'm sure there's already a very neat and efficient code that finds all crossing points for a m*n tray, for a list of segments.
Could you please help me find something of the sort? I've tried searching all over GitHub, SO and Reddit to no avail, my English isn't too good so I might be missing these algorithms bc I'm asking the wrong questions.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This needs more context to be answerable. What is a slicer? What is your input? What is the output? What is wrong with the code you have?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.